# JQuery set form action in ajax script

Tags: jquery

I am using this code:

```
 var frm = $('#myform');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');

            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

I Tried:

```
frm.submit(function (ev) {

   $("#myform").attr('action', 'myurl');

    .....
```

But that didn't work.

Is there a way to set the form action url after "frm.submit(function (ev) {" ?

Comment: Just concatenate? This is a simple question google would have solved easily.

Comment: I tried adding "$("#myform").attr('action', 'theUrl');" after frm.submit(function (ev) { but it didn't work which is why I'm asking

Comment: use `prop` not `attr`

Comment: Tried prop but still no luck

Comment: then something else is going on. are you debugging the form action as you manipulate it? there's so much unsaid details you havent listed

Comment: Please create a fiddle illustrating your issue, something else is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine but you have to enclose it in `DOM ready` or placed it at the end of your page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```